# PowerShell function won't load in profile

Tags: powershell

I'm using this function:

```
function help { get-help $args[0] -detailed | less }
```

When I enter this into the PowerShell console, it behaves correctly. But when I save this in my profile and reload it, the 'help' command correctly uses 'less' but does not display the help topic as -detailed, only the standard short view.

Am I missing something obvious? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you defining your help function in your profile before importing a module that might be overwriting your function?  For example, the PowerShell Community Extensions module defines a help function.  If you import it after you have defined yours, then it wins.  To fix, move your function definition to the end of your profile.